# How do I create a method that takes generics as parameter and calls methods from them?

Tags: java

I have a mixin that I would like to use for several types of requests, e.g. CatRequest and DogRequest. I created a method in the mixin that retrieves certain details from the request, depending on the type of request and sets in the response. Would it be ideal to check for instances and cast them like below or is there a better way to use generics to handle this?

```
default <T> Response setAnimalDetails(final T request, final Response response) {
    Animal animal = new Animal();
    if (request instanceof CatRequest) {
        CatRequest catRequest = (CatRequest) request;
        animal.setType(catRequest.getType());
        animal.setAge(catRequest.getAge());
        animal.setWhiskerLength(catRequest.getWhiskerLength());
    } else if (request instanceof DogRequest) {
        DogRequest dogRequest = (DogRequest) request;
        animal.setType(dogRequest.getAnimalType());
        animal.setAge(dogRequest.getAge());
        // since dogs don't have whiskers, DogRequest doesn't have a whiskers field
    }
    response.setAnimal(animal);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: `animal = null; ... animal.setType(..)` will throw NPE

Comment: Is there a common type for all the requests. If yes, then you can bound your type `T` by that

Comment: If you want to call type-specific methods (`setWhiskerLength()`) there is no other option. Otherwise you might be able to abstract a common interface or superclass.

Comment: @user7 oops, just saw the NPE. There isn't a common type, although I considered creating a common class that they could both extend. Also not sure if that is ideal

Comment: @JimGarrison that seems to be the only option, creating a common class they can both extend and bind my generic type using that

Comment: That makes sense only if there really _is_ an interface or superclass that has all the methods defined in it.  Don't shoehorn everything into a common superclass unless it is truly common.  I.e. don't define a common `setWhiskerLength()` unless all subclasses are guaranteed to need that method.

Comment: Sure, i prefer to use Bound Generic in order to protect the method, this method will not let anyone to use expect who is extending MyRequest 

 `public static <T extends MyRequest> Response setAnimalDetails(T[] anArray, T elem) {

    }`

Otherwise i prefer to use a factory pattern, this will be better actually

Comment: @JimGarrison in my case, one class is a kind-of subset of the other with a few extra fields so you're right, using a common class with fields that one class wouldn't use will not be ideal, might just stick to the method I used above then. Thanks

Comment: @BasilBattikhi there are certain fields that are unique to certain objects and using a factory pattern might be a little tricky

Answer (score 1):

Mixins and generics seem like a roundabout way to achieve something you could just do via inheritance.

```
interface AnimalMaker {
    Animal createAnimal();
}

class CatRequest implements AnimalMaker {
    @Override 
    public Animal createAnimal() {
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        animal.setType(getType());
        animal.setAge(getAge());
        animal.setWhiskerLength(getWhiskerLength());
        return animal;
    }
}

class DogRequest implements AnimalMaker {
    @Override 
    public Animal createAnimal() {
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        animal.setType(getAnimalType());
        animal.setAge(getAge());
        return animal;
    }
}
```

This way, instead of needing that `setAnimalDetails` method, you can simply declare your request as an `AnimalMaker` and do

```
response.setAnimal(request.createAnimal());
```

It would be even better to make subclasses of `Animal` like `Cat` and `Dog`, and make them type parameters for the request classes, but that you can do on your own.